# GitHub action push to pantheon

Tags: github, github-actions, pantheon

I'm trying to create an action that pushes changes to pantheon on every push so we can have more advanced workflows with GitHub but keep the convenience of dev-sites created on pantheon. I have set up 3 secrets

1. SSH_KEY (private key)
2. HOST_IP
3. PANTHEON_REPO (url)

And came up with this action after some Google-ing:

```yaml
name: Push to pantheon
on: [push,pull_request]
jobs:
  pusher:
    name: Push to pantheon
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install SSH key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          known_hosts: 'just-a-placeholder-so-we-dont-get-errors'
      - name: Adding Known Hosts
        run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.HOST_IP }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - name: Push changes
        run: |
          git remote add pantheon ${{ secrets.PANTHEON_REPO }}
          git config --local user.email "..."
          git config --local user.name "Github Action"
          git push pantheon ${GITHUB_REF##*/}
```

However the action fails at `git remote add` with the error:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I created the ssh key specifically for this and added the public key to pantheon.

Comment: It seems you need to set a custom upstream for the site so that it will recognize it

And you need to use tokens and ssh keys instead